# for FILE in Permission denied & ambiguous redirect

Tags: bash

```
for FILE in /data/intervals/*.txt; do
    ID=echo ${FILE}
    /data/bin/Tool -a /data/check.txt -b  ${FILE} > /data/final/Outputed_${ID}
done
```

Giving:

```
-bash: /data/intervals/CT.BP.200.txt: Permission denied
-bash: /data/final/Outputed_${ID}: ambiguous redirect
-bash: /data/intervals/CT.BP.500.txt: Permission denied
-bash: /data/final/Outputed_${ID}: ambiguous redirect
-bash: /data/intervals/CT.BP.50.txt: Permission denied
-bash: /data/final/Outputed_${ID}: ambiguous redirect
....
```

etc.

I can't spot any typo error. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ID=echo ${FILE}
```

does *not* do what you think it does. It actually sets the `ID` environment variable to the value `echo` then tries to *execute* `${FILE}`, hence the permission denied.

If you want to set `ID` based on `FILE`, you need something like one of:

```
ID=$(echo ${FILE} | sed 'some sed command here')
ID=$(basename ${FILE})
```

or, if you just want it set to `FILE` itself:

```
ID=${FILE}
```

But, in that case, `ID` is probably unnecesasary and you can do something like:

```
for FILE in /data/intervals/*.txt; do
    /data/bin/Tool -a /data/check.txt -b ${FILE} > /data/final/Outputed_${FILE}
done
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for FILE in /data/intervals/*.txt; do /data/bin/Tool -a /data/check.txt -b ${FILE} > /data/final/Outputed_${FILE}; done
```

I think you want to do Tool for every file .txt on /data/intervals directory and output your process to a custom Output_my.CT.BP.200.txt

or... do you want to extract ID from filename e and use it on output?

```
for FILE in /data/intervals/*.txt; do IDFILE=$(echo $FILE | cut -d'.' -f3); /data/bin/Tool -a /data/check.txt -b ${FILE} > /data/final/Outputed_${IDFILE}; done
```

I'm using cut for quick-and-dirty solution, you can use other system (awk, sed, perl)